# Named anchor (A) with NAME same as a DIV ID conflict

Tags: url, html, anchor

I am workign on a site that is using a listener for the hash to show and hide content DIVs and to scroll to the named anchor of the same name.

I was having a weird issue where instead of scrolling to the anchor, it would scroll to the DIV with the ID the same as the anchor's name.

Once I changed the DIV ID to something different, the behavior was as expected.

I can't seem to find any documentation on this and was wondering if this is documented behavior.

Code that works:

```
<a name="top">top</a>

<p id="bottomx" style="height: 1800px;">
<a href="#top">top</a>
<a href="#bottom">bottom</a>
<br>
</p>
<a name="bottom">bottom</a>
```

Not working as expected:

```
<a name="top">top</a>

<p id="bottom" style="height: 1800px;">
<a href="#top">top</a>
<a href="#bottom">bottom</a>
<br>
</p>
<a name="bottom">bottom</a>
```

In the second example, it would scroll to the P named "bottom". Likewise, if I make a DIV at the bottom of the page with an ID of "bottom" and I hit page.html#bottom, it scrolls down to that DIV.

Just seems confusing. An idea why this is working this way? Same behavior in Safari and FF.

Comment: Interesting — I'm having a hard time finding this in the HTML5 spec at all.

Comment: If found this in the [HTML4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3): *"The `id` and `name` attributes share the same name space. This means that they cannot both define an anchor with the same name in the same document."*. I assume this was then redefined in the HTML5 spec to consider the common behaviour browsers implemented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`id` has precedence over `name`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html#scroll-to-fragid):

> For HTML documents (and HTML MIME types), the following processing
>   model must be followed to determine what the indicated part of the
>   document is.
>
> 1. Parse the URL, and let fragid be the  component of the
>      URL.
> 2. If fragid is the empty string, then the indicated part of the
>      document is the top of the document; stop the algorithm here.
> 3. Let decoded fragid be the result of expanding any sequences of
>      percent-encoded octets in fragid that are valid UTF-8 sequences into
>      Unicode characters as defined by UTF-8. If any percent-encoded
>      octets in that string are not valid UTF-8 sequences (e.g. they
>      expand to surrogate code points), then skip this step and the next
>      one.
> 4. If this step was not skipped and there is an element in the DOM that
>      has an ID exactly equal to decoded fragid, then the first such
>      element in tree order is the indicated part of the document; stop
>      the algorithm here.
> 5. If there is an a element in the DOM that has a name attribute whose
>      value is exactly equal to fragid (not decoded fragid), then the
>      first such element in tree order is the indicated part of the
>      document; stop the algorithm here.
> 6. If fragid is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the string top,
>      then the indicated part of the document is the top of the document;
>      stop the algorithm here.
> 7. Otherwise, there is no indicated part of the document.

Comment: I guess I never considered that you could use the hash to scroll to an ID or NAME of anything other than <a name="blah"></a>. I learned something new today.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML 4.01 and XHTML 1.0 specifications require that a `name` attribute in an `a` element must not be the same as the value of an `id` attribute, except when set on the same element, the document is in error. Browsers are free to apply their own error handling, which can be rather unplanned.

HTML5 drafts specify complicated error handling rules, but they also declare the `name` attribute in an `a` element as obsolete.

It would be illogical (and formally forbidden) to use the same `id` value to two elements in the same document, as the very purpose, and sole purpose, of `id` is to provide a *unique* identifier for an element. The `<a name=...>` construct predates `id` in the history of HTML and was always meant to play the same role as `id`, in a restricted setting. It is thus natural that it is treated the same way.